# Table View going to video

Tags: iphone, video

Building an app with some video clips.
First we see a table view showing the different clip names.  It has a navigation bar just to make it look nice.  I also have a tab bar at the bottom.
Once the user click on the clip name it get passed on to the next view and the video starts playing.  So far so good.  The problem I have is that the navigation bar and the tab bar is also in that view.
How can I take them away (read clear the window/start a new window)?
How do I get the video to play full screen with nothing from the last view?

Answer (score 0):

to hide the navigation bar, use the UINavigationController's `navigationBarHidden` property.

to hide the tab bar: before you push the new view controller (with the video), set its `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`property. This will hide the tab bar until this UIViewController is popped from the view hierarchy stack.